# Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

This is the log exception:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Libreria] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.angelo.springmvc.model.PrestitoLibro.prestito -> com.angelo.springmvc.model.Prestito] with root cause
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : com.angelo.springmvc.model.PrestitoLibro.prestito -> com.angelo.springmvc.model.Prestito
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(ActionQueue.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(SessionImpl.java:658)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:813)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at com.angelo.springmvc.dao.AbstractDao.persist(AbstractDao.java:34)
    at com.angelo.springmvc.dao.PrestitoLibroDaoImpl.savePrestitoLibro(PrestitoLibroDaoImpl.java:27)
    at com.angelo.springmvc.service.PrestitoServiceImpl.salvaPrestito(PrestitoServiceImpl.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.salvaPrestito(Unknown Source)
    at com.angelo.springmvc.controller.ShoppingCartController.ordinaShoppingCart(ShoppingCartController.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The scenario is the following: I have two entity beans Prestito and PrestitoLibro, a ServicePrestito and a session bean ShoppingCard with a Controller:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRESTITO")
@XmlRootElement
public class Prestito {

    private Integer id;
    private Cliente cliente;
    private Date dataprestito;
    private Set<PrestitoLibro> prestitolibros = new HashSet<PrestitoLibro>(0);

    public Prestito() {
    }

    public Prestito(Cliente cliente, Date dataprestito) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.dataprestito = dataprestito;
    }

    public Prestito(Cliente  cliente, Date dataprestito, Set<PrestitoLibro> prestitolibros) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
        this.dataprestito = dataprestito;
        this.prestitolibros = prestitolibros;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cliente", nullable = false)
    public Cliente  getCliente() {
        return this.cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dataprestito", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public Date getDataprestito() {
        return this.dataprestito;
    }

    public void setDataprestito(Date dataprestito) {
        this.dataprestito = dataprestito;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "prestito")
    public Set<PrestitoLibro> getPrestitolibros() {
        return this.prestitolibros;
    }

    public void setPrestitolibros(Set<PrestitoLibro> prestitolibros) {
        this.prestitolibros = prestitolibros;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Prestito other = (Prestito) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Prestito [id=" + id + ", cliente=" + cliente + ",    dataprestito=" + dataprestito
                + ", prestitolibros=" + prestitolibros + "]";
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="PRESTITOLIBRO")
@XmlRootElement
public class PrestitoLibro {

    private Integer id;
    private Libro libro;
    private Prestito prestito;
    private Integer qta;
    private Double subtotal;


    public PrestitoLibro() {
    }

    public PrestitoLibro(Libro libro, Prestito prestito) {
        this.libro = libro;
        this.prestito = prestito;
    }

    public PrestitoLibro(Libro libro, Prestito prestito, Integer qta, Double subtotal) {
        this.libro = libro;
        this.prestito = prestito;
        this.qta = qta;
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)//, cascade=CascadeType.ALL
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_libro", nullable = false)
    public Libro getLibro() {
        return this.libro;
    }

    public void setLibro(Libro libro) {
        this.libro = libro;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_prestito", nullable = false)
    public Prestito getPrestito() {
        return this.prestito;
    }

    public void setPrestito(Prestito prestito) {
        this.prestito = prestito;
    }

    @Column(name = "qta")
    public Integer getQta() {
        return this.qta;
    }

    public void setQta(Integer qta) {
        this.qta = qta;
    }

    @Column(name = "subtotal", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public Double getSubtotal() {
        return this.subtotal;
    }

    public void setSubtotal(Double subtotal) {
        this.subtotal = subtotal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + id;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        PrestitoLibro other = (PrestitoLibro) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PrestitoLibro [id=" + id + ", libro=" + libro + ", prestito=" + prestito + ", qta=" + qta
                + ", subtotal=" + subtotal + "]";
    }

}


@Component
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION,
    proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class ShoppingCart {

    private Map<Libro, Integer> contents = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<Libro, Integer> getContents() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void setContents(Map<Libro, Integer> contents) {
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public void addLibro(Libro libro, int count){

        if(contents.containsKey(libro)){
            contents.put(libro, contents.get(libro)+count);
        }else{
            contents.put(libro,count);
        }
    }

    public void removeLibro(Libro libro){
        contents.remove(libro);
    }

    public void clearCart(){
        contents.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShoppingCart [contents=" + contents + "]";
    }

    public double getTotalCost(){
        double totalcost = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for(Libro libro: contents.keySet()){
            i =  contents.get(libro);

            totalcost += i * libro.getPrezzo();
        }
        return totalcost;
    }

}
```

The problem occurs when I call `salvaprestito()` here:

```
@Service("prestitoService")
@Transactional
public class PrestitoServiceImpl implements PrestitoService {

@Autowired
private PrestitoDao dao;

@Autowired
private PrestitoLibroDao daoprestitolibro;


public Prestito findById(int id) {
    return dao.findById(id);
}

public void savePrestito(Prestito prestito) {
    dao.savePrestito(prestito);
}

public void updatePrestito(Prestito prestito) {
    Prestito entity = dao.findById(prestito.getId());
    if(entity!=null){
        entity.setCliente(prestito.getCliente());
        entity.setDataprestito(prestito.getDataprestito());
        entity.setPrestitolibros(prestito.getPrestitolibros());
    }
}

public void deletePrestitoBySss(String sss) {
    dao.deletePrestitoBySss(sss);
}

public List<Prestito> findAllPrestiti() {
    return dao.findAllPrestiti();
}

public Prestito findPrestitoBySss(String sss) {
    return dao.findPrestitoBySss(sss);
}

public boolean isPrestitoSssUnique(Integer id, String sss) {
    Prestito prestito = findPrestitoBySss(sss);
    return ( prestito == null || ((id != null) && (prestito.getId() == id)));
}


public void salvaPrestito(Map<Libro, Integer> shoppingcartContents, Cliente cliente){

    Prestito prestito = new Prestito();
    prestito = dao.findById(prestito.getId());
    prestito.setCliente(cliente);
    dao.savePrestito(prestito);
    for(Entry<Libro, Integer> entry: shoppingcartContents.entrySet()){

        PrestitoLibro prestLibro = new PrestitoLibro(entry.getKey(),prestito);

        prestLibro.setQta(entry.getValue());
        prestLibro.setPrestito(prestito);               prestLibro.setSubtotal(entry.getKey().getPrezzo()*entry.getValue());
        daoprestitolibro.savePrestitoLibro(prestLibro);
        prestito.getPrestitolibros().add(prestLibro);
    }   
}
```

And this is the Shopping Cart Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ShoppingCartController {

private static final Logger logger =       LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShoppingCartController.class);

@Autowired
private LibroService libroservice;

@Autowired
private PrestitoService prestitoservice;

@Autowired
private ShoppingCart shoppingcart;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/shoppingcart/add/{libroId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addtoShoppingCart(@PathVariable("libroId") int libroId, @RequestHeader("referer") String rForm) {

    Libro libro = (Libro) libroservice.findById(libroId);
    shoppingcart.addLibro(libro, 1);
    logger.debug("Aggiunto Libro a carrello" + libro);
    return "redirect:" + rForm;

}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/shoppingcart" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewShoppingCart(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("shoppingcart", shoppingcart);
    return "shoppingcart";
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "/shoppingcart/order" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String ordinaShoppingCart(HttpSession session) {
    if(shoppingcart.getContents().isEmpty()){
        return "redirect:/shoppingcart";
    }else{
        Cliente cliente = (Cliente) session.getAttribute("cliente");
            prestitoservice.salvaPrestito(shoppingcart.getContents(), cliente);
            return "redirect:/shoppingcart";    
    }
}
```

These are the Daos:

```
@Repository("prestitolibroDao")
public class PrestitoLibroDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, PrestitoLibro> implements PrestitoLibroDao{


public PrestitoLibro findById(int id) {
    PrestitoLibro prestitolibro = getByKey(id);
    if(prestitolibro!=null){
        Hibernate.initialize(prestitolibro.getId());
    }
    return prestitolibro;
}


public void savePrestitoLibro(PrestitoLibro prestitolibro) {
    persist(prestitolibro);
}


public void deletePrestitoLibroById(int id) {
    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from Prestitolibro where id = :id");
    query.setString("id",(String) Integer.toString(id));
    query.executeUpdate();

}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<PrestitoLibro> findAllPrestitiLibro() {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    return (List<PrestitoLibro>) criteria.list();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<PrestitoLibro> findAllPrestitiLibroByPrestito(int prestitoId) {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id_prestito", prestitoId));
    return (List<PrestitoLibro>) criteria.list();

 }

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<PrestitoLibro> findAllPrestitiLibroByLibro(int libroId) {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id_libro", libroId));
    return (List<PrestitoLibro>) criteria.list();

 }
@Repository("prestitoDao")
public class PrestitoDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, Prestito> implements PrestitoDao{

public Prestito findById(int id) {
    Prestito prestito = getByKey(id);
    if(prestito!=null){
        Hibernate.initialize(prestito.getId());
    }
    return prestito;
}

public void savePrestito(Prestito prestito) {
    persist(prestito);      
    // Save prestito significa salvare il prestito o/e anche PrestitoLibiri
}

public void deletePrestitoBySss(String sss) {
    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from Libro where snn = :snn");
    query.setString("sss", sss);
    query.executeUpdate();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Prestito> findAllPrestiti() {
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    return (List<Prestito>) criteria.list();
}

public Prestito findPrestitoBySss(String sss) {
    System.out.println("SSS : "+sss);
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("sss", sss));
    Prestito prestito = (Prestito)criteria.uniqueResult();
    if(prestito!=null){
        Hibernate.initialize(prestito.getId());
    }
    return prestito;        
}
```

Comment: What's the logic behind this: `Prestito prestito = new Prestito(); prestito = dao.findById(prestito.getId());`?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Looks like he has `Prestito` with `id = null` in the database. It is really blow my mind.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic `Hibernate.initialize(prestito.getId());` is even more strange.

Comment: I fixed it deleting Hibernate.initialize and cao.findById(prestito.getId())....but same problem persists.

Comment: I'm continuing to have problem in salvaprestito()  in PrestitoServiceImpl

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate needs only `id` in `Prestito` to associate it with `PrestitoLibro` by a foreign key. I think, you don't have `id` in `prestito` here

```
prestLibro.setPrestito(prestito);               
daoprestitolibro.savePrestitoLibro(prestLibro);
```

Try to output prestito.getId() before set it to `prestLibro`.

If you really don't have `id` the reason may be with this generation strategy

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
```

or you don't have a transaction with `@Transactional` in the `PrestitoServiceImpl` so `dao.savePrestito(prestito)` doesn't save `prestito` at all. May be adding of your spring xml configuration in your question let to help you.

You do some unnecessary stuff in your method so it should be

```
public void salvaPrestito(Map<Libro, Integer> shoppingcartContents, Cliente cliente){

    Prestito prestito = new Prestito();
    prestito.setCliente(cliente);
    dao.savePrestito(prestito);
    for(Entry<Libro, Integer> entry: shoppingcartContents.entrySet()){

        PrestitoLibro prestLibro = new PrestitoLibro(entry.getKey(), prestito);

        prestLibro.setQta(entry.getValue());
        prestLibro.setSubtotal(entry.getKey().getPrezzo() * entry.getValue());
        daoprestitolibro.savePrestitoLibro(prestLibro);
    }   
}
```

You don't need `prestLibro.setPrestito(prestito)` and 
`prestito.getPrestitolibros().add(prestLibro)`.